# Am I correct in assuming that "echo" and "cat" are too fast for the "time" command to time?

Tags: performance, shell, ubuntu, unix, time

I was converting a few shell subprocesses to JavaScript in a Node.js project, and out of curiosity I wanted to see the difference between `cat` and `echo` with the `time` command (nothing to do with the project, just wanted to see how fast they were).

```bash
time echo "Hello World!"
```

Which is when I got the following output:

```bash
Hello World!

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Not quite zero but I got a similar output from the `cat` command:

```bash
time cat compile.js
```

```bash
import Build from "./src/build.js";
Build.main();

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Some or all of the `time` fields say `0m0.000s`. Does this mean it's processing so fast that it can't be measured with `time`? If not, what's happening?

Comment: It helps to understand what each of the three represents, but in general, yes, these commands are so simple that they complete in less than the `time` command's increment. In general, user and sys time should be non-overlapping, but time spent waiting for I/O to complete isn't counted towards either, which is why their sum may not equal the real time.

Comment: The granularity of `time` is too large for `echo` and small `cat` operations probably.

Comment: Time have a pretty heavy granularity (>1 ms) while process (in cache) takes no more than few hundred of milliseconds to be executed on most platforms. `cat` can be slowed down by the disc access or by the terminal synchronization (terminals are slow). Consider trying `time cat compile.js > /dev/null`.

Comment: You could write a loop which executes a command many times, and measure the time for the loop. In particular with `echo`, I guess that the major part of the time being spent is consumed by your terminal to acutally show/render the output. To find the time the `echo` itself needs, I would redirect the output to `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo` (as a shell built-in) probably takes less than 1 millisecond to execute.

Note the rather large real time is due to the inital startup for `/bin/echo`, which I virtually never use. Subsequent runs are much faster as the executable is cached in memory and doesn't need to be loaded into disk again

`cat` takes 3 milliseconds, virtually all of which is spent in user-level code, not system-level code. The real time is the same as the user time because, for example, the process is not interrupted to do something else while it is waiting for I/O to complete. On a busier system (or for a longer running command), you may see the real time exceed the sum of the user and system times.

---

Using `/bin/echo` instead of the shell built-in can be instructive, because you get very different results for the first execution and subsequent executions:

```bash
bash-4.4$ time /bin/echo "Hello World!"
Hello World!
    
real    0m0.113s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.003s
```

```bash
bash-4.4$ time /bin/echo "Hello World!"
Hello World!
    
real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.001s
```

I virtually never use `/bin/echo`, so this is probably the first time I've used it since the last time I rebooted my computer. Much of the 113 milliseconds is spent simply loading the executable into memory, where it gets cached, so it doesn't need to be reloaded for the second execution.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain it to me, I appreciate it.